# Use complex types in imported XSD from importing XSD without changing existing XMLs

Tags: xml, xsd

**Question: Is it possible to import complexTypes into a schema without having to declare both namespaces in the resulting XML file?**

---

I know that similar questions have been asked, but none I've seen have covered my specific need which takes a bit to explain:

Let's say in a prior version of a piece of software we shipped a schema that would look like this example:

specific.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://test.com/specific" xmlns="http://test.com/specific" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0">
    <xs:complexType name="testType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="testSubElement" type="testSubElement"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="testSubElement"></xs:complexType>

    <element name="testType" type="common:testType"></element>
</xs:schema>
```

to be used like this:

file.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testType xmlns="http://test.com/specific" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://test.com/specific specific.xsd">
    <testSubElement/>
</testType>
```

We actually had several similar schemas, so later we decided to pull out the common definitions into a core file and import that file into the relevant schemas:

common.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://test.com/common" xmlns="http://test.com/common" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0">
    <xs:complexType name="testType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="testSubElement" type="testSubElement"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="testSubElement"></xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

specific.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://test.com/specific" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:specific="http://test.com/specific" xmlns:common="http://test.com/common" version="1.0">
    
    <import namespace="http://test.com/common" schemaLocation="common.xsd"/>

    <element name="testType" type="common:testType"></element>
</schema>
```

However, now we're getting issues with existing files not validating correctly like they used to:

```
$ xmllint --schema specific.xsd myFile.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testType xmlns="http://test.com/specific" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://test.com/specific specific.xsd">
    <testSubElement/>
</testType>
myFile.xml:4: element testSubElement: Schemas validity error : Element '{http://test.com/specific}testSubElement': This element is not expected. Expected is ( {http://test.com/common}testSubElement ).
myFile.xml fails to validate
```

Is it possible for us to modify our schema into this common/specific pattern without needing to make changes to the XML files conforming to the schema, while preserving the validation? How would it be done?

Comment: I think you would need to use the same targetNamespace in both schemas and rather use `xs:include` instead of `xs:import` to include the common types in the specific ones. That way you can have separate files but types/elements will be for the same namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the same namespace for elements defined in both schema documents, then both schema documents should have the same target namespace and you should use `xs:include` rather than `xs:import` to combine them.